# Trying to figure out how to assign specific colors to specific data points in Highchart Pie chart

Tags: highcharts, colors, series

I have a case where I don't want the data point to be included if it is null, but I wish the color for each displayed point be the same regardless. So, in my ethnicity example, a particular instance might yield Asian, Hispanic, and Other and another might yield African American, Asian, and Pacific Islander. I would like the Asian in both of these instances to be represented by the same color instead of just the first color in the colors list for the former and the second color in the color list for the latter.

I tried including the color inline, but could not get it to work. I included the PHP code so the null choices would not display. Below is the porion of the code for the series.

```
    var series = [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Ethnicity',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [
    <?php if($afam <> 0){echo"['African American', "  . $afam . "],";} ?>
    <?php if($asia <> 0){echo"['Asian', "  . $asia . "],";} ?>
    <?php if($hisp <> 0){echo"['Hispanic/Latino', "  . $hisp . "],";} ?>
    <?php if($naam <> 0){echo"['Native American', "  . $naam . "],";} ?>
    <?php if($other <> 0){echo"['Other', "  . $other . "],";} ?>
    <?php if($pais <> 0){echo"['Pacific Islander', "  . $pais . "],";} ?>
    <?php if($twop <> 0){echo"['Two or More', "  . $twop . "],";} ?>
    <?php if($whit <> 0){echo"['White', "  . $whit . "],";} ?>

    ]
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use color inline with data but you should define your data as array of objects instead of array of arrays and use ***name***, ***y*** and ***color*** attributes in each one of them. In your case it would be something like below (replace **YOURCOLOR** with your distinct colors name or #hex):

```
var series = [{
type: 'pie',
name: 'Ethnicity',
colorByPoint: true,
data: [
    <?php if($afam <> 0){echo"{'name': 'African American', 'y': "  . $afam . "},";} ?>
    <?php if($asia <> 0){echo"{'name': 'Asian', 'y': "  . $asia . ", 'color': 'YOURCOLOR'},";} ?>
    <?php if($hisp <> 0){echo"{'name': 'Hispanic/Latino', 'y': "  . $hisp . ", 'color': 'YOURCOLOR'},";} ?>
    <?php if($naam <> 0){echo"{'name': 'Native American', 'y': "  . $naam . ", 'color': 'YOURCOLOR'},";} ?>
    <?php if($other <> 0){echo"{'name': 'Other', 'y': "  . $other . ", 'color': 'YOURCOLOR'},";} ?>
    <?php if($pais <> 0){echo"{'name': 'Pacific Islander', 'y': "  . $pais . ", 'color': 'YOURCOLOR'},";} ?>
    <?php if($twop <> 0){echo"{'name': 'Two or More', 'y': "  . $twop . ", 'color': 'YOURCOLOR'},";} ?>
    <?php if($whit <> 0){echo"{'name': 'White', 'y': "  . $whit . ", 'color': 'YOURCOLOR'},";} ?>

]
}];
```

Comment: Glad to hear that Erick. Please accept the answer if it helped you :)